# IOS App keeps Images in Memory

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have an app that has two view controllers with images

when I launch the app the memory increases and when I then segue to the other view controller and load the 2nd image ( I have a button to do this ) the memory goes up again.. this is what I would have expected..

However, when I dismiss the 2nd VC controller or removing the image in the 2nd VC  via a button, and then dismiss the controller , the memory never goes down.

why is this, with an app with lots of images it could get large.. how do I release the memory of the 2nd VC or at least the memory of the 2nd image.

Im looking at memory under debug navigator in Xcode 8, when running the app.

[xcode project can be found here , very simple](https://github.com/bradmill/memtest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will cache images. The [documentation for `UIImage(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) says:

> #### Discussion
>
> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns the variant of that image that is best suited for the main screen. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or from an available asset catalog, and then returns the resulting object.
>
> The system may purge cached image data at any time to free up memory. Purging occurs only for images that are in the cache but are not currently being used...
>
> #### Special Considerations
>
> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using
>   [imageWithContentsOfFile:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init). This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Note, you don't control when this cache is freed. The OS does that as it sees fit (and generally in response to memory pressure).

Bottom line, we often don't worry about inherent caching by `UIImage` and simply ensure the app doesn't have its own memory issues, e.g. make sure `deinit` is getting called and/or use the "Debug Memory Graph" feature in Xcode to watch memory graph. Or if you want, programmatically set the image using [`UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init).

Comment: thank you , that makes sense.. quick follow up question .. I have image files that are x1,x2,x3.. if I use UIImage(contentsOfFile:), does Xcode still display the right file automatically or will I have to use a device detection function e.g if iphone7Plus then UIImage(contentsOfFile:...."@x3"

Comment: The `contentsOfFile` does not automatically grab the image of the right scale, so you'd have to do that yourself (though I'd use the `scale` of the `UIScreen` rather than referring to specific devices). So, you have to pick between `UIImage(named:)`, which caches and picks appropriate image asset for you, or `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` which neither caches nor picks the appropriately scaled asset.

Comment: @Rob "The `contentsOfFile` does not automatically grab the image of the right scale" _Yes it does_. That is one of the most important things it does. If your app bundle contains _pic.png_ and _pic@2x.png_, and you have the path to _pic.png_, `contentsOfFile` will load _pic@2x.png_ on a double-resolution device.